# How to input date on Orientdb data base with csv file and Json parser

Tags: json, csv, datetime, orientdb

I have a problem when I try to put a datetime. I read a CSV with my Json to put the data on Orientdb data base

csv:

```
id;id_tag;tag_name;date
1;1;tag1;"2014-3-24 6:49:2"
2;1;tag1;"2009-11-22 13:12:7"
3;1;tag1;"2014-10-18 14:47:6"
4;1;tag1;"2013-2-10 15:23:27"
```

Json:

```
{
 "config": {
    "log": "debug"
  },
  "source": { "file": { "path": "/Users/jonathanmahe/Documents/OrientTest/GeospatialTest/bd1000/bd1000.csv" } },
  "extractor": { "csv": {
    "separator": ";",
    "columns": ["id:Integer","id_tag:Integer","tag_name:String","date:dateTime"] } },
  "transformers": [
    { "command": { "command": "INSERT INTO Tag(id,id_tag,tag_name,date) values('${input.id}','${input.id_tag}','${input.tag_name}','${input.date}')"} }
  ],            
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
        "dbURL": "remote:localhost/databases/bd1000",
        "dbUser": "admin",
        "dbPassword": "admin",
        "serverUser": "root",
        "serverPassword": "root",
        "dbType": "graph",
        "batchCommit": 1000
    }
  }
}
```

the error I get is:

> ERROR exception=Error on conversion of date 'Mon Mar 24 06:49:00 CET 2014' using the format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Someone has an idea?

Comment: Hello, which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

before launching the etl import you need to modify the datetime format:

- connect to the db
- `alter database DATETIMEFORMAT "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"`
- run etl script

---

```
orientdb {db=bd1000}> select from tag

+----+-----+------+----+------+--------+-----------------------------+
|#   |@RID |@CLASS|id  |id_tag|tag_name|date                         |
+----+-----+------+----+------+--------+-----------------------------+
|0   |#21:0|Tag   |1   |1     |tag1    |Mon Mar 24 06:49:00 CET 2014 |
|1   |#22:0|Tag   |2   |1     |tag1    |Sun Nov 22 13:12:00 CET 2009 |
|2   |#23:0|Tag   |3   |1     |tag1    |Sat Oct 18 14:47:00 CEST 2014|
|3   |#24:0|Tag   |4   |1     |tag1    |Sun Feb 10 15:23:00 CET 2013 |
+----+-----+------+----+------+--------+-----------------------------+
```